# NSString variable to UITextField's text on Swift

Tags: ios, nsstring, swift, uitextfield

I need to fetch a NSString from the NSMutableDictionary and assign it to UITextField's text.

But I am getting an exception ;  unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When I log the string it writes to console.

My code is as below;

```
    let tempString:NSString! = tempDict.objectForKey("name") as? NSString

    NSLog("%@",tempString)

    cell.textLabel.text = tempString  //This line gives the exception
```

Comment: Well, if the string's okay, then it's probably the cell or the textLabel. Are you sure those aren't nil? Did you forget to connect one of them up in Interface builder?

Comment: show your declaration of the cell

Comment: var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

        if (cell == nil)
        {
              cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stop this by safely unwrapping cell.textLabel by adding an if statement.

```
if var label = cell.textLabel{
    label.text = "This is a title"
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This. It Helped to get out from the same problem I was having

let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                self.lblUserName.text = userName as String